# Mouse cursor hangs very regularly

Tags: 15.04, mouse, mate

Every few minutes (and sometimes repeatedly) my mouse cursor will hang (stop responding to any input) for a few seconds. This is incredibly annoying but compounding the problem is that every time this happens my `xinput set-button-map` settings are lost and I have to run the command again to restore functionality on my mouse (Evoluent 3). I've also had more serious hangs where the mouse gives up completely (and I need to unplug it and plug it in again to make it work) or where the entire system hangs and I need to hold the power button to kill it. As it stands my machine is borderline unusable.

I assume this is a driver problem but I've no idea which logs to look in to get a sense of where the problem is coming from. Any advice generally (debugging misbehaving USB devices) or specifically (Evoluent 3 hanging regularly) would be much appreciated.

I'm on 15.04 Vivid Mate with the 3.19.0-51-generic x86_64 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late, but owning two Evoluent Vertical Mice (models 2 and 4), I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is. In fact, it's a cable problem. Most Evoluent mice have the same problem, both of mine had it. The way the main cable passes inside the mouse, it tends to break from the inside after a couple of years of use. You will find instruction videos on how to fix this. I tried myself, and it works. For example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EE_Z-vXzDTw

If you don't feel like repairing it yourself or simply don't have the tools to do it, you can also replace the cable, and it's cheap. Here's a link sent to me by an Evoluent employee. He told me the inside connector is pretty standard, and it should work like a charm.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/FOR-New-Microsoft-Intellimouse-Explorer-IE3-0-Gaming-Mouse-Mice-USB-Line-cable-/161706519199?hash=item25a675aa9f

Hope this helps!